# Change default crop origin of a featured image in Wordpress (thumbnail)

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails, crop, wordpress-featured-image

I would like to change the way Wordpress crops the **featured images thumbnail**. The generated thumbnails are cropped from the center. Can I control that to set up to **top left** ?
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126285/wordpress-post-thumbnail-crop-question-is-this-even-possible) mentions a [plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1733/user-friendly-cropping-of-post-thumbnails), but it doesen't really exists :3
And the [Scissors plugin](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/scissors-for-wordpress-29-also-works-on-30-hurray) seams not to affect featured image thumbnail.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good idea to modify the core of Wordpress. You can use the plugin [Thumbnail Crop Position](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thumbnail-crop-position/) to select a corner or the center point of the image from where the image will be cropped.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, and at best is a recommendation which should be a comment

Answer (score 2):

```php
update_option( 'thumbnail_crop', array( 'left', 'top' ) );
```

Values can be: left, center, right

Answer (score 1):

In **wp-includes/media.php**, line 360, I found :

```
    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
```

...and changed to :

```
    $s_x = 0;
    $s_y = 0;
```

... to define crop to **top right**.

Comment: modifying WP core means this will all be erased the moment WP is updated, as well as considered compromised by security scanners. This should be done with a filter instead